# SQL Selecting Max Value 4 Joins

Tags: sql, database, join, select, mariadb

I´m stuck with this Query. I want to get the following information from my Database:

User.username, Satz.Gewicht, Satz.Wiederholungen, ubungen.Name and Training.Datum

The Clue is, that I want to get this Columns for every different Exercise (ubungen.id).

I Tried with this:

```
SELECT
   a3.Datum, 
   a4.username, 
   a2.Name, 
   max(Gewicht) as Gewicht, 
   Wiederholungen
from satz a1 
INNER JOIN ubungen a2 ON a1.UBID = a2.ID 
INNER JOIN training a3 ON a1.TID = a3.ID
INNER JOIN user a4 ON a3.UID = a4.ID
GROUP BY a1.UBID
```

But Somehow I´m getting the right Weight -> max(Gewicht) , but the wrong user.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a Screenshot of my database design: 
[image: Database Design]

EDIT: 
When using every column in my Group by I get Multiple Columns like this:

[image: Example]

But i Just want the one in the middle at it is the one with the highest Gewicht.

Example of what I want:

[image: Example2]

This is the whole resultset after Joining the information I want. Now I just want the Lines that are marked in red. There are some lines having the same "max(gewicht)", no matter which of the ones to pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just looking for the record with the maximum value for each ubid:

```
select x.Ubid,x.Datum,x.username,x.name,x.Gewicht,x.Wiederholungen
from
(SELECT
   a1.Ubid,
   a3.Datum, 
   a4.username, 
   a2.Name, 
   Gewicht, 
   Wiederholungen,
   row_number() over (partition by a1.ubid order by Gewicht desc) as rownum1
from satz a1 
INNER JOIN ubungen a2 ON a1.UBID = a2.ID 
INNER JOIN training a3 ON a1.TID = a3.ID
INNER JOIN user a4 ON a3.UID = a4.ID ) x
where x.rownum1=1
```

I have made use of the row_number function to pull the record with the highest Gewicht value. Hope this helps.

Edit: Adding a db-fiddle, it's working fine in this example:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ac9caf422a06feb6e7c05c1a68995f5

Since row_number is not working, you can use an inner join to get the max value:

```
select x.Ubid,x.Datum,x.name,x.Gewicht,max(x.Wiederholungen) as Wiederholungen,max(x.username) as username
from
(SELECT
   a1.Ubid,
   a3.Datum, 
   a4.username, 
   a2.Name, 
   a1.Gewicht, 
   a1.Wiederholungen
from satz a1 
INNER JOIN ubungen a2 ON a1.UBID = a2.ID 
INNER JOIN training a3 ON a1.TID = a3.ID
INNER JOIN user a4 ON a3.UID = a4.ID ) x
INNER JOIN 
(select ubid,max(Gewicht) as max_Gewicht from satz group by ubid) y
ON x.ubid=y.ubid and x.Gewicht=y.max_Gewicht
Group by x.Ubid,x.Datum,x.name,x.Gewicht
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209190/discussion-on-answer-by-cr7sms-sql-selecting-max-value-4-joins).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use all the columns in the `GROUP BY` except aggregated function column

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
    a3.Datum, a4.username, a2.Name, max(Gewicht) as Gewicht, Wiederholungen 
FROM satz a1 
INNER JOIN ubungen a2 
    ON a1.UBID = a2.ID 
INNER JOIN training a3 
    ON a1.TID = a3.ID
INNER JOIN user a4 
    ON a3.UID = a4.ID
GROUP BY 
    a3.Datum, a4.username, a2.Name, Wiederholungen
```

Comment: This shows me multiple Columns. I just want the one where satz.Gewicht is the highest value per Exercise (satz.ubid)

Comment: added the screenshot of output into my post.

Comment: You also need data of this `a3.Datum, a4.username, a2.Name, Wiederholungen` columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your query runs, but it's malformed.

Columns not specified in the `GROUP BY` clause should be aggregated. MariaDB (and MySQL) are notorious by allowing non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.

**Solution**: Just add all non-aggregated columns to the `GROUP BY` clause to solve your issue, as in:

```
GROUP BY a1.UBID, a3.Datum, a4.username, a2.Name, Wiederholungen
```

As it is, MariaDB is selecting values **randomly**. Today you see the wrong values, but maybe tomorrow they are good. You don't want a query behaving like this.